# is there a way to display an imageview in android "half cut" on screen?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm currently developing an android game and my designer thought on this screen for my game:
[image: screen of my game]

as you can see, the roof in this image is cut a little on the sides and top. But she send me the full roof, as shown in the image below:

[image]

my question is: is there a way to show this roof "half-cut" on android tablet of 7 inches and the same roof not half-cut on tablets with bigger screens?

Answer (score 0):

Get 2 images and have that image depending on the screen size

Comment: um, ok, but how can I make the roof half-cut on the smaller screen?